# in my app xml files aren't getting navigation Directions/Args classes

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

So have been using the navigation component just lately and one problem I am facing is the I can't get reference of my navigation Directions/Args class on data binding here is my code

```
<data>
        <variable
            name="args"
            type="com.jaydip.todotut.fragments.update.UpdateFragmentArgs"/>
            // here UpdateFragmentArgs in not recognized by the lint 
</data>
```

here I am getting errors in other files Directions and Args classes are working fine
my dependencies

```
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.5"
```

Build Gradle(project)

```
plugin{ id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'}
```

I tried rebuilding project,cleaning and rebuilding and also make build as directory

https://ibb.co/5G03Tjb

Comment: android studio arctic fox 2020.3.1

Answer (score 0):

You must have android.useAndroidX=true in your gradle.properties file as per Migrating to AndroidX.

To generate Java language code suitable for Java or mixed Java and Kotlin modules, add this line to your app or module's build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"
```

Alternatively, to generate Kotlin code suitable for Kotlin-only modules add:

```
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
```

UPDATE

```
<data> <import type="yourNavArgs"/> </data> –
```

Comment: already have it

Comment: in my adapter class i am able to use Directions and args but not in xml

Comment: You can't use XML either.

Comment: no i have implement in kotlin  but not seeing in xml

Comment: here is the code withot the problem  `private val args by navArgs<UpdateFragmentArgs>()`

Comment: this is working

Comment: not variable 

using import keyword.

Comment: <data>
    <import type="yourNavArgs"/>
</data>

Comment: no solving this also

Comment: if you have some time then you can see it in my repo https://github.com/jaydip430/todotut

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same Android Studio version that you mentioned and found that the generated files by the plugin are not being used by the studio. Therefore I added the below piece of code in my app Gradle file

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/navigation-args'
        }
    }
}
```

Add the above code in Gradle > Clean Project > Rebuild Project.